# Understanding increasing and damping exponential signal

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

I have the following function skatches of a complex exponential function $e^{\sigma + j\omega t}$:
[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8APD.png)

But the sketch does not make sense to me at all because if I worked it out right the **real part of the function is periodic**:

$e^{\sigma + j\omega t} = e^{\sigma} \cdot (\cos(\omega t) + j\sin(\omega t))$

So the **real part** would be...

$e^{\sigma} \cdot \cos(\omega t) \text{ with } \sigma = 0.1, \omega = 1\\\Rightarrow e^{0.1} \cdot \cos(t)$

...which seemingly is a periodic function which does not increase or damp anyway.

Where is my fallacy?

Glad for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function of the picture a pair of brackets is missing:

$e^{\sigma + j\omega t}$  should be $e^{(\sigma + j\omega )t}$

Thats the magic!